# Zend models and database relationships

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

i'm starting with Zend Framework and I'm a little bit confused with models and relathionships (one-to-many, many-to-many etc).

The "Zend Framework Quick Start" says to create a Zend_Db_Table, a Data Mapper and finally
our model class

Suppose we have a database like this:

```
table A (
id integer primary key,
name varchar(50)
);

table B (
id integer primary key,
a_id integer references A
);
```

then, i'll create:

```
Application_Model_DbTable_A extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract,
Application_Model_AMapper,
Application_Model_A,

Application_Model_DbTable_B extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract,
Application_Model_BMapper,
Application_Model_B,
```

if I understood, i've to store the references informations in 
Application_Model_DbTable_A:

```
protected $_dependentTables = array('B');
```

and Application_Model_DbTable_B:

```
protected $_referenceMap = array(
    'A' => array(
        'columns' => array('a_id'),
        'refTableClass' => 'A',
        'refColums' => array('id')
    )
);
```

and my models class:

```
class Application_Model_A
{
    protected $_id;
    protected $_name;

    public function __construct(array $options = null)
    {
        if(is_array($options)) {
        $this->setOptions($options);
        }       
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $method = 'set' . $name;
        if (('mapper' == $name) || !method_exists($this, $method)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid property');
        }
        $this->$method($value);
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        $method = 'get' . $name;
        if (('mapper' == $name) || !method_exists($this, $method)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid property');
        }
        return $this->$method();
    }

    public function setOptions(array $options)
    {
        $methods = get_class_methods($this);
        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            $method = 'set' . ucfirst($key);
            if (in_array($method, $methods)) {
                $this->$method($value);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->_name = (string) $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->_name;
    } 

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->_id = (int) $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getId() 
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }

class Application_Model_B
{
    protected $_id;
    protected $_a_id;

    public function __construct(array $options = null)
    {
        if(is_array($options)) {
        $this->setOptions($options);
        }       
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $method = 'set' . $name;
        if (('mapper' == $name) || !method_exists($this, $method)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid property');
        }
        $this->$method($value);
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        $method = 'get' . $name;
        if (('mapper' == $name) || !method_exists($this, $method)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid property');
        }
        return $this->$method();
    }

    public function setOptions(array $options)
    {
        $methods = get_class_methods($this);
        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            $method = 'set' . ucfirst($key);
            if (in_array($method, $methods)) {
                $this->$method($value);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function setA_id($a_id)
    {
        $this->_a_id = (int) $a_id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getA_id()
    {
        return $this->_a_id;
    } 

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->_id = (int) $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getId() 
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }
```

it's that right?

Comment: Did you try it, does it work? If not, what error messages do you get?

Comment: i think he's trying to understand how zend framework handles many to one and one to many mapping and perhaps cascading effect.

Comment: Can you try reducing your code by half and ask more specific questions resp. write down your loud thinking protocoll.

Answer (score 0):

Well let's assume you have a db table called `products`. You want to access this table and work with the data.

First you need in `models/dbtable/` folder a `Product.php` file to tell zf where to look for the data:

```
class Default_Model_DbTable_Product extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'products';

}
```

So `$_name` is the name of the db table. Second you need a class where you store all the information like product attributes. Let's say a product has just a name:

```
class Default_Model_Product{

    protected $_name;

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->_name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->_name;
    }

    public function __construct(array $options = null) {
        if (is_array ( $options )) {
            $this->setOptions ( $options );
        }
    }
    //you need the methods below to access an instanz of this class
    //put it in every model class
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $method = 'set' . $name;
        if (('mapper' == $name) || ! method_exists ( $this, $method )) {
            throw new Exception ( 'Invalid product property' );
        }
        $this->$method ( $value );
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        $method = 'get' . $name;
        if (('mapper' == $name) || ! method_exists ( $this, $method )) {
            throw new Exception ( 'Invalid product property' );
        }
        return $this->$method ();
    }

    public function setOptions(array $options) {
        $methods = get_class_methods ( $this );
        foreach ( $options as $key => $value ) {
            $method = 'set' . ucfirst ( $key );
            if (in_array ( $method, $methods )) {
                $this->$method ( $value );
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Finally you need a mapper class where you actually access the data. You retrieve the data from the table and store it as objects in an array:

```
class Default_Model_ProductMapper {

    protected $_dbTable;

    public function setDbTable($dbTable) {
        if (is_string ( $dbTable )) {
            $dbTable = new $dbTable ();
        }
        if (! $dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
            throw new Exception ( 'Invalid table data gateway provided' );
        }
        $this->_dbTable = $dbTable;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDbTable() {
        if (null === $this->_dbTable) {
            $this->setDbTable ( 'Default_Model_DbTable_Product' );
        }
        return $this->_dbTable;
    }
   //e.g. fetch all
    public function fetchAll() {
        $resultSet = $this->getDbTable ()->fetchAll ();
        $entries = array ();
        foreach ( $resultSet as $row ) {
            $entry = new Default_Model_Product ();
            $entry->setName ( $row->name );
            $entries [] = $entry;
        }
        return $entries;
    }
}
```

This is really straight forward ;)

Comment: You haven't mentioned a relationship or the related model here at all?

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend you to use another DB-Framework in your MVC-System.

Zend isn't quite nice with Databases and it's IMO too complicated/ too much code to write.
There are Frameworks which play very nice with Zend (VC) like PHPActiveRecord...

--> http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Frameworks

Comment: Relationships are very easy with nearly no coding-efford:

http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Associations